# Why doesn't @Getmapping work in some instances?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my controller, the following use of @GetMapping works:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/new")
public String newEssay(){
    return "articles/essay_new";
}
```

But it doesn't work like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/essays/{essayId: [0-9]+}")
//@RequestMapping(value = "/essays/{essayId:[0-9]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEssay(Model model,
                       @PathVariable("essayId") long essayId) throws NoFindException, ForBiddenException, ParseException {
    JsEssay jsEssay = jsBiz.get(JsEssay.class, essayId);

    model.addAttribute("jsEssay", jsEssay);
    return "articles/essay";
}
```

I tried it with Spring 4.3.3 and 5.0.0.M5.

Config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"me.freezehome.blog"},
            excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION,     value = EnableWebMvc.class)
            }
)
public class RootConfig {
}



@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({WebSecurityConfig.class})
public class WebConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping(){
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    }
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter(){
        return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    }
}
```

Google results:

- [Add support for @GetMapping, @PostMapping etc. introduced in Spring 4.3 in ControllerLinkBuilder #471](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/471)
- [GetMapping and PostMapping annotations Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680370/getmapping-and-postmapping-annotations)

github source: [lbfreeze-blog-develop](https://github.com/lbfreeze/lbfreeze-blog/tree/develop)

Comment: Have you tried removing the space after `essayId:`?  (Also, you don't need to write `value =`)

Comment: @bphilipnyc It works after I remove space after `essayId:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the space after `essayId:`

Also, you don't need to write `value =` for `@GetMapping`.